# Sort Facets by Index with non-ASCII values

Tags: solr, faceted-search

We have a field 'facet_tag' that contains tags describing a product. Since the tags are in german, they may contain non-ASCII characters (like umlauts). Here are some possible values:

"Zelte" 
"Tunnelzelte" 
"Äxte" 
"Sägen" 
"Softshells"

Now if we query solr for the facets with a query like:

```
http://<solr_host>:<solr_port>/solr/select?q=*&facet=on&facet.field=facet_tag&facet.sort=index
```

The sorted result looks like this:

```
<lst name="facet_counts">
    <lst name="facet_queries"/>
    <lst name="facet_fields">
        <lst name="facet_tag">
            <int name="Softshells">1</int>
            <int name="Sägen">1</int>
            <int name="Tunnelzelte">1</int>
            <int name="Zelte">1</int>
            <int name="Äxte">2</int>
        </lst>
    </lst>
    <lst name="facet_dates"/>
    <lst name="facet_ranges"/>
</lst>
```

The tag "Äxte" should be the first item, followed by "Sägen". Obviously Solr does not handle non-ASCII characters well in this case (which is also stated in the documentation for faceted search, see http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.sort)

Is there any way to let Solr sort these values properly without normalizing umlauts (since we show the values to the user)?

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, I actually accepted some more answers now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [`ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory`](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory):

> Converts alphabetic, numeric, and symbolic Unicode characters which are not in the first 127 ASCII characters (the "Basic Latin" Unicode block) into their ASCII equivalents, if one exists.

This way what you index becomes normalized (for example Äxte becomes indexed as Axte), but what is stored doesn't change. That's why you should then get the expected sorting, but the content you'll show will still be the original one (Äxte for example).

**UPDATE**
The solution doesn't apply to facets since they use the indexed values. Using the `ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory` you can have the right sort but you'll see normalized character as output as well. Basically you can have the right sort but wrong output or wrong sort but right output. Unfortunately I don't know any other solution.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out here!

I think the problem is that faceted search always uses the indexed values instead of the stored ones (see http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrFacetingOverview). So when I add the filter to the index analyzer, the sorting works as expected, but the output changes from "Äxte" to "Axte" as well.

Comment: I see! I should have read the question deeper, of course you see the indexed results as faceted output. Need to think about this, it's more challenging that I initially thought...

Comment: It seems like there really isn't a way to to do this without changing the output. We will sort the facets on the application side instead.